# Color code Columns?

Tags: list, column

we have imported a spreadsheet into a new list on a SharePoint 2013 site and as a result have a lot of data with many columns.

What we want to do is colour code it as per the original spreadsheet - you can see the highlighting in the screenshot taken from excel below.

I've previously managed to highlight rows based on a field value however in this case we need the ability highlight single cells or an entire column of the same colour.

I've done a quick google on this and cannot find much evidence of other people being able to do this.

Any ideas??
Thanks

[image]

Comment: If you want to replicate this screenshot results in a _View_ of a list, you can use  [Client Side Rendering](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views)  _N.B you should have a criteria for set colors to columns and cells._

Comment: Include a screenshot of the rules you used to color this Excel sheet. And yes CSR is the most liekly candidate, but depending on your rules there might be an alternative.

Comment: The coloring was done manually on the spreadsheet.
I haven't been able to find any CSR details for columns, only for rows.